# trying to understand this linkedlist insertion code

Tags: c

i have this code

```
struct Node {
   int data;
   struct *Node next;
};

struct Node *head;

void insert(int x) {
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

int main()
{
     head = NULL;
}
```

I'm following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAZ8CyDY56s), It looks like the code works. I'm having a hard time putting it together though.

we have a node head which is initially set to NULL in the main method.

The **linkedlist** holds an int and next. This insert code sets data to an int and next to head. Then it sets head to temp.

Wouldn't this make give head the int and then make it point to itself over and over again since we set temp.next to head and then head = temp ?

So far I've only done iterations on **linkedlist** where the last next is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This code inserts an item at the **beginning** of a linked list - it creates a new node, sets its data, and makes its `next` point to the current `head`.

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->data = x;
```

We have a new node, and have set its value.

```
temp->next = head;
```

The `head` (if any) will come *after* this element in the list.  That means this should be our new `head`.

```
head = temp;
```

And now it is.

If `head` was `NULL`, this list has no `next` entry, as expected.

If `head` was not `NULL`, this node is the new head, and its `next` points to the *second* element in the list (the old `head`).